# Unable to unsubscribe user from titanium cloud

Tags: push-notification, titanium, cloud, subscribe

I am a beginner in Titanium APP development and need your help in push notifications. The issue I am experiencing is:

I create a "User A" on cloud from APP and subscribes it for push notifications and get notifications successfully. But when I try to recreate another "User B" after unsubscribing "User A" and logout "User A" from a same device and subscribe "User B" for push notifications and successfully receiving notifications for "User B" but also I am still receiving notifications for "User A" which is not correct. However, in "Subscribed Devices" in cloud APP management there is only one user is listed with device token which is "User B".

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

There was an error with ACS. Maybe it's fixed with SDK 3.0.2.GA? https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-12356